# Asp.net updatepanel Listbox not refreshing layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, listbox, asp.net-ajax

so my problem is fairly simple i have 2 list-boxes and one button.
when an item is selected in listbox2 and the button is clicked i would like to add the selected item to listbox1.

And it all seams to work until I add the second item. then listbox1  doesn't refresh it's items...

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ListBox2.Items.Add(new ListItem("1", "1"));
            ListBox2.Items.Add(new ListItem("2", "2"));
            ListBox2.Items.Add(new ListItem("3", "3"));
            ListBox2.Items.Add(new ListItem("4", "4"));
            ListBox2.Items.Add(new ListItem("5", "5"));
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox2.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(ListBox2.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `UpdateMode=conditional` to your `UpdatePanel`

And set `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />`

```
  <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
                <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
            </ContentTemplate>

            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>

        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

Comment: With this code you execute partially your code and you don't post all your page.

Comment: any Ide's on how to fix it? the first item appears fine it's the second one that dos not...
in debug mode on the second click i can see that listbox1 has one item before I add the second one...

Comment: You can persist with ViewState , you don't re-bind your ListBox1, EnableViewState is set to true by defaut

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :) 
The problem was that Listbox1 SelectionMode = Single... so when the result is returned the
error is on the client side. solution is to deselect the item before you add it to the other list. (or make a new with the value and text from the selected one)

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox2.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {

            ListItem item = ListBox2.SelectedItem;
            item.Selected = false;
            ListBox1.Items.Add(item);

        }
    }
```