# Web application page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I have a listbox and two buttons that change the listitems in that listbox. They are in a wizard and when I click on the buttons, I do not want the page to load. I want to stay in the same page without loading a new one and change the list items.

The listbox retrieve its item from a sql database (there are thousands of rows)

I know this may be done in AJAX but with asp.net 2.0, this is a difficult task to accomplish. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you might find this useful..shows use of AsyncPostBackTrigger http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384747/asp-net-updatepanel-listbox-not-refreshing-layout

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UpdatePanel` control with `Triggers` and `UpdateMode="Conditional"`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx

```
           <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1"  runat="server" />
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >

              <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonId" />
              </Triggers> 

             <ContentTemplate>

                        <asp:ListView ID=".." runat="server"/>
                        ....
             </ContentTemplate>

            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I can't add an updatepanel (ie: <asp:UpdatePanel ...). Is there something i need to include (library?)

Comment: Nitrodbz you can add reference to System.Web.Extensions.dll

Comment: You'll also need to add `<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>` to the markup (VS templates usually add this by default in newer versions).

Comment: don't have that reference. Do you think its because i'm using asp.net 2.0?

Comment: Ok i'll think of updating my .net to 3.5. Is their any disadvantage in doing so (will my existing code be affected in anyway)?

Answer (score 0):

If you can, i would definatelly use some jsavascript framework to deal with Ajax ( JQuery/Dojo for example )